# Any Mods watching this?

Tags: discussion, support

It's been flagged several times already.  This guy is clearly a troll, his account needs to be dumped.

[Why isn't Angelo Pappas doing his job?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/113584/why-isnt-angelo-pappas-doing-his-job)

Comment: The first flag is an hour old.  Question deleted, I'm going to check the user as a dupe of another suspended account.

Comment: User was indeed a duplicate of a suspended user.  user deleted.  Thanks.

Comment: @BCdotWEB They're gone.